# jQuery global variables

Tags: jquery, variables, global-variables

I am trying do "globalize" my variables to use them in multile functions but with no result. Where am I wrong?
thank you so much!

Here is the code:

```
var my_sidebar_clicked = $('#dash #sidebar ul#main_menu li');
var my_dash_main_content = $('#dash > #main_content');


function mainmenu_selection() {

            //var my_sidebar_clicked = $('#dash #sidebar ul#main_menu li');
            //var my_dash_main_content = $('#dash #main_content');

            my_sidebar_clicked.children().click(function() {
                var el = $(this);
                var mylink = el.attr('href');

                $('#dash #sidebar ul#main_menu li a').removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');

                //$('#dash #main_content').load("ajax/" + mylink);

                my_dash_main_content.html('<img class="loader_img" src="common/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                my_dash_main_content + $(".loader_img").fadeIn(200);
                my_dash_main_content.load("ajax/" + mylink, function(response, status, xhr) {
                        if (status == "error") {
                                var msg = "Oops... sembra esserci un problema, ti preghiamo di riprovare ";
                                my_dash_main_content.html("<h4 class='error_msg'>" + msg + "</h4>"/* + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText*/);
                        }
                });

                return false;
            });
}
```

Comment: can we see the html? also you sure the selectors are correct?

Comment: Is either thing you're selecting updated dynamically? If so the previous selector values could be obsolete. Also those selectors look unnecessarily complicated, assuming you don't improperly have duplicate IDs, the 1st is equivalent to `#main_menu li` and the 2nd is equivalent to `#main_content`

Answer (score 1):

Taking a wild guess, placing the variable initializations inside a block executed after the document is ready would fix the problem.

Try this instead of the first two lines:

```
$(function() {
    window.my_sidebar_clicked = $('#dash #sidebar ul#main_menu li');
    window.my_dash_main_content = $('#dash > #main_content');
});
```

Comment: I would advise _not_ polluting the global scope, and just declaring the variables (and everything else) inside of the document ready callback.

Comment: @MattBall: If I read the question correctly, the OP needs these variables to be visible from multiple JS files. So putting them inside a function would not be an option.

Comment: Multiple functions != multiple files.

Comment: @MattBall: For some reason I read "multile" not as multi**p**le but as multi**fi**le... you got it right.